# Как подружить обычное приложение на Python и Django

Tags: python, django, cron

Есть вэб-приложение на Django, в котором настраивается управление адресами почты клиентов. Есть простое python-приложение, рассылающее сообщения по расписанию с использованием CRON. Сейчас они никак не связаны. Не могу разобраться, можно ли в обычном приложении обратиться к базе django-проекта через модели, чтобы использовать базу django-приложения для рассылки.

Comment: Используйте библиотеку threading, она позволяет создать мультипоточность. Код написать не могу, тк вы не дали подробности.
Документацию можно почитать тут:https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

Comment: Без правки django проекта?

Comment: Да, можно: [Using django for CLI tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32091771/14775762).

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Спасибо, похоже, то, что нужно!

Comment: @root_of_the_live Спасибо, тоже интересная тема, пригодится в моем решении.